# Prevent typing spaces in an HTML text box with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

So I've got an `HTML` form that users can type in. How can I use javascript/jQuery to immediately and seamlessly remove spaces from a text box when one is put in? I've been researching the `.val()` jQuery method and came up with this:

```
$('input').keydown(function() {
    str = $(this).val();
    str = str.replace(/\s/g,'');
    $(this).val(str);
});
```

That does weird things to removing text and the spaces still show up on keystroke, they just get removed on the following keystroke. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could prevent it from being added at all by checking whether the key pressed is the space bar and returning `false` if so:

```
​$("input").on("keydown", function (e) {
    return e.which !== 32;
});​​​​​
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/USJws/).

Comment: @JacksonGariety - What's wrong with it / What do you mean by "gremlins"?

Comment: There are hidden HTML entities in the code above. If you copy/pasted it from some webpage there were some hidden HTML junk there. I manually typed it out and worked, thanks.

Comment: @JacksonGariety - Oh I see. I didn't copy it, I wrote it in JSFiddle and pasted it from there (same fiddle that I linked to in the answer). Not sure what JSFiddle adds in.

Comment: Yeah, I tend to get gremlins when I use JSFiddle.

Comment: It does do some odd things sometimes (like if I press Enter it won't insert a new line). Anyway, I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: Can we achieve this for special characters also??

Comment: @JamesAllardice What about if user pastes spaces how can we prevent that?

Answer (score 12):

Try use `keyup`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/5Tax7/)**

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
    str = $(this).val();
    str = str.replace(/\s/g,'');
    $(this).val(str);
});
```

Comment: That also adds it and quickly removes it, visibly, and also you can't select text to delete it (with CMD+A). :/

Comment: I think this option is very good. Because it also voids copy and pasted spaces.