# Disable spaces in Input, AND allow back arrow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I am trying to disable spaces in the Username text field, however my code disables using the back arrow too. Any way to allow the back arrow also?

```
    $(function() {
         var txt = $("input#UserName");
         var func = function() {
                      txt.val(txt.val().replace(/\s/g, ''));
                   }
         txt.keyup(func).blur(func);
    });
```

fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/EJFbt/

Comment: Try using the method described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11268278/185078)

Comment: Your fiddle it's working fine here on firefox, back arrow works.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You may add `keydown` handler and prevent default action for space key (i.e. `32`):

```
$("input#UserName").on({
  keydown: function(e) {
    if (e.which === 32)
      return false;
  },
  change: function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, "");
  }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/EJFbt/1/

Comment: Why not _explain_ the proposed solution? Also, isn't the `change` handler redundant?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `change` is needed for cross browser text paste.

Comment: Okay; that makes sense. It would be great if that kind of explanation were given in the answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit proposed solution: disable spaces in field (whether typed or pasted in) AND enable back arrow

Comment: @jakeed1: You and I understand the answer, but the OP may not. Answers contain _text explanations_ supplemented by code examples. Not just silent code dumps.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I guess *jakeed1* and the OP is the same person :) BTW, I think our discussion (plus your answer) is more than enough the get the idea.

Comment: @VisioN: `s/the OP/some other future visitor/`

Comment: Note that the `change` event occurs on blur, not as the user types.

Comment: @David is right, though this behavior may differ across browsers. You would have to add the substitution code to the `keyup` event instead.

Comment: @dualed No, `keyup` will reset the caret position to the end, while `change` *always* fires on losing focus (when caret position is not important).

Comment: @VisioN unless you only replace when there actually is a space character in the string.

Comment: @dualed also, keyup is not reliable to detect text paste as there are many ways to paste text (f.ex using the mouse and OS menu). The best way is to run an interval that looks for change every x milliseconds.

Comment: `KeyboardEvent.which` is being removed the web standards, so avoid using it if possible, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which)

Comment: @tmvnty what you see here is a different `which` from jQuery. It is still available and fully supported: https://api.jquery.com/event.which/.

Comment: what happend if I paste? instead of key press?

Answer (score 31):

This seems to work for me:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return event.charCode != 32">
```

Comment: also works for me (Safari 15.0, Firefox 93)

Comment: actually, `event.charCode` is deprected [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode). please use [key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead

Comment: @HadiKAR  replacing `event.charCode` with `event.key` doesn't seem to work. Can you provide a full example?

Comment: @PhilipBorbon have you tried convertinv `event.key` into a charcode such as `event.key.charCodeAt(0) !== 32` ? as in [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charCodeAt.asp)?

Comment: @HadiKAR I ended up using `event.key != " "`. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't "disable" the back arrow — your code keeps replacing all the text outright, whenever you press a key, and every time that happens the caret position is lost.

Simply don't do that.

Use a better mechanism for banning spaces, such as [returning `false` from an onkeydown handler when the key pressed is `space`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11268278/560648):

```
$(function() {
    $("input#Username").on("keydown", function (e) {
        return e.which !== 32;
    });​​​​​
});
```

This way, your textbox is prohibited from receiving the spaces in the first place and you don't need to replace any text. The caret will thus remain unaffected.

---

#### Update

[*@VisioN*'s adapted code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14236954/560648) will also add this space-banning support to copy-paste operations, whilst still avoiding text-replacement-on-`keyup` handlers that affect your textbox value whilst your caret is still active within it.

So here's the final code:

```
$(function() {

    // "Ban" spaces in username field
    $("input#Username").on({

       // When a new character was typed in
       keydown: function(e) {

          // 32 - ASCII for Space;
          // `return false` cancels the keypress
          if (e.which === 32)
             return false;
       },

       // When spaces managed to "sneak in" via copy/paste
       change: function() {
          // Regex-remove all spaces in the final value
          this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, "");
       }

       // Notice: value replacement only in events
       //  that already involve the textbox losing
       //  losing focus, else caret position gets
       //  mangled.
    });​​​​​
});
```

Comment: All so close.. but if you copy and paste a name that has a space (which my team does for some reason), it still keeps the space.

Comment: @jakeed1 The code will only remove the spaces when you focus another element, since the change only occurs on blur. Code is working perfectly for our needs.

Comment: @julealgon: I fixed jakeed's problem 7 minutes after that comment. Over two years ago! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try checking for the proper key code in your function:

```
$(function(){
    var txt = $("input#UserName");
    var func = function(e) {
      if(e.keyCode === 32){
        txt.val(txt.val().replace(/\s/g, ''));
      }
    }
    txt.keyup(func).blur(func);
});
```

That way only the `keyCode` of `32` (a space) calls the replace function. This will allow the other `keypress` events to get through. Depending on comparability in IE, you may need to check whether `e` exists, use `e.which`, or perhaps use the global window.event object. There are many question on here that cover such topics though.

If you're unsure about a certain `keyCode` try this helpful [site](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes).

Comment: That'll still mangle the caret position when you _do_ press `space`, which is undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

One liner:

```
onkeypress="return event.which != 32"
```