# How to find the specific input box that triggered keydown event from many other inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `div`containing many `input` boxes. I don't want the user to be able to submit a space key into the field.
**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
Input1<input type="text">
Input2<input type="text">
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".container :input").keydown(function(event){
    if(event.which == 32){
        //code to change the specific text box to = ""
    };
});
```

I have tried `this.val() = ""` but that doesn't seem to work for some reason.

If there is an alternative through html to stop the input boxes accepting space then that will work to.

Comment: Use `this.value` or `$(this).val()`, as `val()` is jquery function and `this` refers to underlying DOM object so you have use it with `$(this)`

Comment: [Disable spaces in Input, AND allow back arrow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236873/disable-spaces-in-input-and-allow-back-arrow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/fg6p1ujz/

```
$(".container :input").keydown(function(event){
    if(event.which == 32){
        //uncomment if you want to clear the field 
        // $(this).val("");
        return false
    };
});
```

If you want to disable a key you can return false whenever the user presses the key. You can clear the field by using $(this).val("")

Answer (score 0):

Within an event handler the `this` keyword refers to the element which raised the event. As such, you can do this:

```
$(".container :input").keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 32) {
        $(this).val('');
    };
});
```

Note that I have wrapped `this` in a jQuery object, so that I can use jQuery methods, such as `val()` or `prop()`, on it. Then I used the setter of `val()` to set the value of the field to `''`.

You could also do this in native JS, by using the `value` property of the DOMElement itself:

```
this.value = '';
```