# Prevent spaces in input field on keypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, keypress

I'm using the following code to detect multiple keys on a keypress event:

```
var down = [];
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
     down[e.keyCode] = true;
}).keyup(function (e) {
     if (down[17] && down[32]) {
          // Do something
     }
     down[e.keyCode] = false;
});
```

However, this hotkey (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>) is meant to be used while an input field has focus. So whenever I press the key combination, it also adds a space to the input field.

How can I prevent this from happening? I've looked at ways to disable spaces in input (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236873/disable-spaces-in-input-and-allow-back-arrow)), but I can't figure out how to make it work inside my keypress event only.

Comment: What about a different approach? You could handle the keyup event and remove any blank space that is present. You wouldn't need to check for key codes, etc.

Comment: `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` is what you seek young padawan.

Comment: I was not able to get `e.preventDefault()` working in my code. It would simply disable all input if I added it to the keydown event. Adding it to the keyup event did nothing. I got it working by following your advice, @MelanciaUK. On keyup, I simply remove the last character in the input field. While it doesn't prevent space from being added, it removes it immediately. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a different approach, as MelanciaUK suggested.

On the keyup event, it removes the last character in the input field.

```
var down = [];
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
     down[e.keyCode] = true;
}).keyup(function (e) {
     if (down[17] && down[32]) {
          // Do something
          input = $(':focus');
          input.val(function (index, value) {
               return value.substr(0, value.length - 1);
          });
     }
     down[e.keyCode] = false;
});
```

While it doesn't prevent the space from being added, it removes it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EJFbt/114/). I hope it helps.

```
var down = [];
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
     down[e.keyCode] = true;
}).keypress(function (e) {
     if (down[17] && down[32]) {
         var $sampleTextBox = $("input#sampleTextBox");
          $sampleTextBox.val($sampleTextBox.val().replace(/\s/g, ''));
         alert($sampleTextBox.val().length)
          alert("Ctrl + Space Pressed!");
     }
     down[e.keyCode] = false;
}).keyup(function (e) {
     if (down[17] && down[32]) {
         var $sampleTextBox = $("input#sampleTextBox");
          $sampleTextBox.val($sampleTextBox.val().replace(/\s/g, ''));
         alert($sampleTextBox.val().length)
          alert("Ctrl + Space Pressed!");
     }
     down[e.keyCode] = false;
});
```

--

Thanks,

SuperCoder