# HTML Input field: remove spaces with jQuery 3.2.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am working on a HTML / PHP form to register users.

With the following code I reach it, that no blank spaces in the input field arise.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function stripspaces(input)
    {
        input.value = input.value.replace(/\s/gi,"");
        return true;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    Enter your username: <input onkeydown="javascript:stripspaces(this)" name="field_with_no_spaces" type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

But I read ([Disable spaces in Input, AND allow back arrow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236873/disable-spaces-in-input-and-allow-back-arrow)) about a better method to do this. I tried it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("input#UserName").on({
            keydown: function(e) {
                if (e.which === 32)
                    return false;
            },
            change: function() {
                this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, "");
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Enter your username: <input id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work, can somebody help me? Is it because of my jQuery version?

Thank you,

Comment: you should still validate with php, as any JS can easily be bypassed ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your js code after the DOM element has been created (so just before the closing body tag in your example), or use a "$function" declaration. Otherwise, when $("input#UserName") is evaluated, there is no input created yet and thus the handler won't be attached

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("input#UserName").on({
        keydown: function(e) {
            if (e.which === 32)
                return false;
        },
        change: function() {
            this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, "");
        }
    });
    })
</script>
</head>
<body>
Enter your username: <input id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now it works :). I owe you a coffee.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to wrap your code in a [`.ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) callback, see snippet.

Currently when your code is executed, the DOM has not been loaded into memory and parsed, so the JavaScript code calls elements that do not yet exist, and therefore cannot add event listeners.

```
<input onkeydown="javascript:stripspaces(this)" name="field_with_no_spaces" type="text" id="" />
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("input#UserName").on({
        keydown: function(e) {
          if (e.which === 32)
            return false;
        },
        change: function() {
          this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, "");
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  Enter your username: <input id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`onkeypress='return event.charCode != 32'`

This would prevent `space` to be entered and does not rely on JQuery.

But you should still validate with php, as any JS can easily be bypassed ;)