# Disable spaces in input field on svelte

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, sveltekit

I am trying to disable spaces in the Username text field

As [Disable spaces in Input, AND allow back arrow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236873/disable-spaces-in-input-and-allow-back-arrow), this should be like this:

```html
<input on:keydown={(e) => e.which !== 32} />
```

But I still able to input space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution where spaces are prevented of being typed and removed from pasted text [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/9a2b4938b55d4738a76ac21c9c365766?version=3.47.0)

```
<script>
    let value
    
    function handleKeydown(event) {
        // prevent that a space is typed
        if(event.code === 'Space') event.preventDefault()
    }
    
    function handleInput(event) {
        // remove spaces from pasted text
        value = value.replaceAll(' ', '')       
    }   
</script>

<input type="text"
             bind:value
             on:keydown={handleKeydown}
             on:input={handleInput}>
```

Answer (score 1):

`which` is not a valid event property anymore. For keyboard events, you'll want to use [KeyboardEvent.code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) or [KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key).

In your use case, using the former:

```
<input on:keydown={({ code }) => code !== "Space"} />
```

this will only disallow the spacebar, however, so you'd likely have to add handling for other whitespace keys like `Tab`, etc.

Alternatively, you could turn your input into a controlled input and `trim` the content whenever it changes (in effect disallowing whitespace input of any kind).

Answer (score 1):

For standard event handling the return value has no meaning. You should use `preventDefault`.

Example code:

```html
Broken:
<input type="text" on:keypress="{e => e.charCode != 32}"/> <br/>

Works (not recommended):
<input type="text" onkeypress="return event.charCode != 32"/> <br/>

Works with "on:"
<input type="text"
       on:keypress={e => { if (e.charCode == 32) e.preventDefault(); }} />
```

(Also, the `keypress` event is deprecated and should no longer be used. Further, this is only a partial solution, as the user can still paste any values.)

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/0013731c954a4b009e854d699d6ed3cf?version=3.47.0)

Answer (score 0):

I propose to remove space for a tag in svelte like this:

```
<a href="#{HtmlLibrary.title}"></a>
```